# opencart arabic language not working perfectly

Tags: opencart

I've downloaded a free arabic language pack from extensions directly and uploaded as mentioned in different blogs by uploading the arabic folder to languages folder and adding support from dashboard.

Now the problem is that the language pack is working on some areas mainly in content area. but the header links and footer links are not getting changed. they are just getting right aligned when i choose arabic.

How can i solve this problem ? There is no such issue in opencart forum.

Thanks

P.S The information pages links are hardcoded in my header.tpl and footer.tpl files.

```
http://khalifaelectronics.com/index.php?route=common/home
```

Comment: Did you check whether you have got arabic language values in database and language files for header and footer controllers?

Comment: @sankar V Where can i check that sir ?

Comment: Yes there are header and footer files in common folder of language

Comment: I mean in your arabic language folder

Comment: @SankarV yes thera are folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login into admin.
2. Go to `Catalog > Information`.
3. Edit and add translations for all pages.

That's it. Have a nice day !!

Comment: So we have to do it manually ? Do i need to place additional stylesheets ?

Comment: Yes. We've to do it manually because it's your data. Please check and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

if you want change about us or so you need goto `Catalog > Information > Aboutus` or as you have in your menu bar then as shown below you need to manually define your title in different languages like i have Francis and espanol so i have edited both tabs you can use [Google translator](http://translate.google.com)  for better conversion e.g `about us = حول بنا`

[image]

hope it ll help you :)